# Getting array data from PHP to jQuery for outputting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is the partial code from the remove PHP file:

```
if($action == 'trackings_get') {
    $result = $trackings->get(getCourierSlugByID($GLOBALS['tracking_id']), $GLOBALS['tracking_id']);
    $result_history = $result['data']['tracking']['checkpoints'];

    echo json_encode($result_history);

    // debugging
    //pretty_print($result_history);
}
```

Here is the JS from the remote site i am trying to call the data for:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/login/tracking.php',
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    action: action,
    tracking_id: tracking_id
  }, 
  success: function(json){ 
    //debug
    alert(JSON.stringify(json));
  }
});
```

Comment: convert `alert(JSON.stringify(json));` to `console.log(json);` and see what is coming in console. Now you can use that `json` (if output is coming fine.) . You used `dataType: "json",` so no need of `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: I tried that but nothing was returned, and look in network i see the POST but no result, if i change to GET i see the returned array though but not sure right way to get this data and handle it...

Comment: change POST to GET and then try to use the data according to your wish

Answer (score 1):

i try this code in inspect element  in this page https://tracking.ambientlounge.com/

```
function test(){
$.ajax({
  url: 'your url',
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    action: "action",
    tracking_id: "tracking_id"
  }, 
  success: function(json){ 
    //debug
    console.log(json);
  }
});


}
```

result is array . dont need JSON.stringify .

Comment: ali zarei  you used hardcoded value in url and hens POST method and data sending become useless. That's not the right way to do so

Comment: it is a sample  only !!

Comment: then it's wrong way to giving sample. This sample will serve future visitors too. So it will misguide them as well.

Comment: Yes I agree, can you please modify this Answer as dont want URLs or screenshots to this system. I have adjusted the questiont o remove the POST URL to remove this but please adjust your reply.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function test(){
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    action: action,
    tracking_id: tracking_id
  }, 
  success: function(json){ 
  }
});


}
```